# Blurry / Abysmal resolution on Electron Version 25.3.1 on MAC

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-react

[image]

The text in the image looks blurred, and not crisp, not able to find the solution.

Can anyone help me with this